# In a Kaggle kernel while having selected the GPU option when checking torch.cuda.is_available(), it says is not available

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, kaggle

I created a kernel for a finished Kaggle competition in which i used pytorch. When checking if cuda is available, it returns False.

I checked the GPU option from settings and it says it is on in the bottom bar with resources info. I tried to restart the session without any changes.
What could be the problem? (cpu only pytorch installed maybe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the selected docker configuration from settings. Selecting the "Latest Available" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start the kernel and `turn-on` the GPU in settings option, on the right-hand side control panel. Then run following commands.

```
    [1]:import torch
    [2]:torch.cuda.device_count()
    Out[2]:1

    [3]:torch.cuda.is_available()
    Out[3]:True
```